# How to remove a group of characters from a string object in javascript

Tags: javascript, str-replace

How to do this in a more "elegant way"?

```
var str = obj.property.toString(); //str value = (55.930385, -3.118425)
var remesp = str.replace(" ","");
var rempar1 = remesp.replace("(","");
var rempar2 = rempar1.replace(")",""); //rempar2 value = "55.930385,-3.118425"
```

Comment: What does `str` look like?

Comment: I have added str value... thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a [regular expression character class (aka "character set") `[...]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-sets):

```javascript
var str = "(55.930385, -3.118425)";

str.replace(/[ ()]/g, ''); // => "55.930385,-3.118425"
```

In the example above, the regex `/[ ()]/` matches any space or open/close parenthesis character.

Answer (score 1):

The more elegant way would be using proper regex syntax in replace().

Answer (score 1):

Switch ( and ) with [ and ] and use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to get the numbers into your new array.

```
var str = "(55.930385, -3.118425)".replace("(","[").replace(")","]"); 
var coords = JSON.parse(str);
```

If you need to support older browsers, you will need to use a JSON.parse shim or another solution.